# Is Average Accuracy An Ill-Defined Metric?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, accuracy, sensitivity-specificity

Five people each took a 100 question yes/no question test. I have their individual accuracy scores and was planning to report their average.

However, I was informed that "You cannot take an average of percentages derived from categorical variables" and I am trying to understand the full scope of that statement as I've never heard push-back from studies reporting the average accuracy.

Comment: Can you please add some clarification? What's your goal? What do you want to know or calculate? What's the question here?

Comment: I am looking to just calculate the average accuracy and a confidence interval. I thought this was a simple but was informed by a statistician that it is not because each question on the test was a true/false and thus a categorical variable and apparently that makes averages of the accuracy ill-defined. But this doesn't make sense to me, and I'm trying to understand more

Answer (score 1):

It reports exactly what it sounds like, but that’s perhaps not what you want. Imagine getting $1/2$ the first time and $94/98$ the second time. Combined, you are $95/100$, but the average accuracy is $\dfrac{\dfrac{94}{98}+\dfrac{1}{2}}{2}\approx0.73$.

While you’re quite not wrong to say that the average accuracy is $0.73$, you decide which is more representative of your data. I’d go with the $95\%$, and I would expect most people to interpret “average accuracy” this way.

Comment: If you follow (or at least understand) basketball, baseball, or American football, I can make a solid analogy using the sport of your choice.

Comment: Skateboarding please!

Comment: In the context here if I'm trying to understand the average accuracy of the test taker, so it seems that doing the typical average accuracy would be the most reasonable way of getting a sense of the performance rather than combining. 

My primary concern is that if this type of averaging is invalid because the underlying variable is "categorical." I've never heard of anything like this and can't find anything online, and trying to understand why I was told it was incorrect to do so.

Comment: @pw-314 In my example, which makes more sense, an average accuracy of $73\%$ or an average accuracy of $95\%?$